# Mixing Convolutional Neural Networks and "regular" Feed Forward Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've just been watching some computerphile videos on ANNs. And in one of them the guy talked about figuring out the price of a house according to a picture.

At that moment an idea came into my head. Maybe this problem could be better solved if it had more information that the picture simply cannot give. For example, area, number of bathrooms, number of bedrooms, neighbourhood info (schools nearby, hospitals, etc).

The information I just gave could also be used to determine the same thing the picture tries to determine but it could be solved using a different type of ANN ("regular" feed forwardd network deep learning techniques). And in my understanding these type of informations are treated differently than the ones obtained from the figure.

My question is: Is it possible to mix the 2 different types of data?
For example:

image kernel outputs -> input neurons
other information    -> other inputs

And then the input data from the kernels and the information is "mixed" in the hidden neurons. Am I dreaming? I don't know practically anything about convolutional neural networks and I only have a vague idea about how the input to the system works (I think I learned it from the computerphile videos, they really explained it like I'm five), but is it possible to do what I'm thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to mix the 2 different types of data?

Yes, no problem.

You can also have more than one image as input, e.g. Bojarski, Mariusz, Davide Del Testa, Daniel Dworakowski, Bernhard Firner, Beat Flepp, Prasoon Goyal, Lawrence D. Jackel et al. "[End to End Learning for Self-Driving Cars.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07316)" arXiv preprint arXiv:1604.07316 (2016).

[image]

Comment: Ok. This mixes 3 CNNs and generates an angle output for the steering wheel. This is great, amazing article. But does it mean that I could mix other data like number of passengers, extra weight, wind speed and consumption so that it can steer better, as well as optimize fuel consumption? The type of input data seems to be so different (and the training algorithms look like they need to be different as well)

Comment: I can't upvote your answer because I have less than 15 reputation

Comment: @morcillo yes you could mix other data, no issue. Typically those CNN networks end with some feedforward layers, you could plug your other data there.